# python3: Counting repeated occurrence in a list

Tags: python-3.x

Each line contains a special timestamp, the caller number, the receiver number, the duration of the call in seconds and the rate per minute in cents at which this call was charged, all separated by ";”. The file contains thousands of calls looks like this. I created a list instead of a dictionary to access the elements but I'm not sure how to count the number of calls originating from the phone in question

```
timestamp;caller;receiver;duration;rate per minute
    1419121426;7808907654;7807890123;184;0.34
    1419122593;7803214567;7801236789;46;0.37
    1419122890;7808907654;7809876543;225;0.31
    1419122967;7801234567;7808907654;419;0.34
    1419123462;7804922860;7809876543;782;0.29
    1419123914;7804321098;7801234567;919;0.34
    1419125766;7807890123;7808907654;176;0.41
    1419127316;7809876543;7804321098;471;0.31

   Phone number || # |Duration | Due     |
   +--------------+-----------------------
   |(780) 123 4567||384|55h07m53s|$ 876.97|
   |(780) 123 6789||132|17h53m19s|$ 288.81|
   |(780) 321 4567||363|49h52m12s|$ 827.48|
   |(780) 432 1098||112|16h05m09s|$ 259.66|
   |(780) 492 2860||502|69h27m48s|$1160.52|
   |(780) 789 0123||259|35h56m10s|$ 596.94|
   |(780) 876 5432||129|17h22m32s|$ 288.56|
   |(780) 890 7654||245|33h48m46s|$ 539.41|
   |(780) 987 6543||374|52h50m11s|$ 883.72|

list =[i.strip().split(";") for i in open("calls.txt", "r")]
print(list)
```

Comment: what are you counting exactly?

Comment: Number of calls originating from the caller's phone

Answer (score 1):

I have very simple solution for your issue:

First of all use `with` when opening file - it's a handy shortcut and it provides sames functionality as wrap this funtion into try...except. Consider this:

```
lines = []
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lines.append(line.strip().split(";"))
print(lines)

counters = {}
# you browse through lists and later through numbers inside lists
for line in lines:
    for number in line:
        # very basic way to count occurences
        if number not in counters:
            counters[number] = 1
        else:
            counters[number] += 1
# in this condition you can tell what number of digits you accept
counters = {elem: counters[elem] for elem in counters.keys() if len(elem) > 5}
print(counters)
```

Comment: HeY @PatNowak I got to add the number of calls, but now i'm wondering how i should add up the dues?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
import csv
import collections

Call = collections.namedtuple("Call", "duration rate time")

calls = {}
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for time, nofrom, noto, dur, rate in csv.reader(infile):
        calls.get(nofrom, {}).get(noto,[]).append(Call(dur, rate, time))

for nofrom, logs in calls.items():
    for noto, callist in logs.items():
        print(nofrom, "called", noto, len(callist), "times")
```